# Facebook invitable friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I somehow get bigger image than the one API returns in picture.data.url ?

For in-App friends I have userId that I can use like following but Inviteable friends return token instead of userId:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?width={1}&height={2}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the Invitable friends API, you can scale the picture that comes with it with a type or your own width and height.

For a pre-defined type:

```
/me/invitable_friends?fields=picture.type(large)
```

For your own width and height:

```
/me/invitable_friends?fields=picture.width(150).height(150)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example will help:

```
FB.api('/me/invitable_friends?fields=picture.type(large)', function (response) {
// picture url will be in the response
}
```

The picture types are at this url

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the picture.data.url of invitable_friends to access a higher quality image (possibly the original image or at least the same dimensions as the originally uploaded image).

Example:

https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/t1.0-1/c62.62.780.780/s50x50/482877_10151573704436719_2137579306_n.jpg

Remove everything between the domain and filename, i.e:
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/482877_10151573704436719_2137579306_n.jpg

A simple enough javascript function would parse the URL:

```
 function GetFullImage(url){
    var filename = url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    return url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/",8)+1) + filename;
  }

GetOriginalImage(friend.picture.data.url);
```

Also, you can modify the 50x50 part to give a larger dimension size but this isn't a guaranteed solution because:

1) The larger dimension might not be available (the user may have uploaded a small image)

2) The cropping info (c62.62.780.780 in above example) may only show the image correctly at 50x50.
I'm sure there's probably a straightforward enough solution to get your desired size but I'm afraid I haven't yet put the required time into this. Hope the above helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the picture.data.url of invitable_friends to access a higher quality image with your own dimensions. In this Objective-C example we use height=120 and weight=120

```
#define IMAGE_PATTERN @"s120x120"

NSString *url_ = @"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/1477386_637922472919990_2075386170_n.jpg?oh=afaeeb2448654c3ae05fb87d1a23b504&oe=54F2E920&__gda__=1424976270_d2b5b60376149424116b38783b0ddde0";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_];
NSString *newUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@/%@/%@",
                 url.scheme,
                 url.host,
                 IMAGE_PATTERN,
                 url.pathComponents.lastObject];
NSLog(@"newUrl: %@", newUrl);
```